# Trouble Running Google Search Console API on Cloud Environment: Authentication Issue

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, cloud, streamlit

I have a script that connects to the Google Search Console API, and it runs exactly as I want on my local machine.

The function that connects to the script looks like this:

```
def create_search_console_service():
# Google Cloud Project Client ID & Client Secrets
client_id = 'MY-CLIENT-ID'
client_secret = 'MY-CLIENT-SECRET'
oauth_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Create an instance of OAuth2WebServerFlow
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, oauth_scope, redirect_uri)

# Path to store the credentials
credentials_path = 'credentials.dat'

if os.path.exists(credentials_path):
    # Load the credentials from the file
    storage = Storage(credentials_path)
    credentials = storage.get()
else:
    # Execute the OAuth flow with automated code retrieval
    credentials = run_flow(flow, Storage(credentials_path))

# Build the service
service = build('searchconsole', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

return service
```

On my local machine, this script opens a new window in my browser, asks for my credentials, and runs as I want it to run.

But when I deploy this to Railway App (or Streamlit cloud), it simply doesn't open anything, and the script doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Is my authentication not correct for a cloud environment?

I have already tried removing the creation of the .dat file. I also attempted to upload it to Railway and Streamlit platforms. Moreover, I tried implementing authentication on the same page instead of opening a new one, but unfortunately, I haven't achieved any positive results so far.